# Copy contents of directory to an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsfilemanager

I have many images of jpg format in a folder named **Wallpaper** .
I am trying to read the contents of directory and store them in an array using the following code :

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Wallpaper" error:NULL];
```

but its not working. I am unable to fetch them into the array.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Where is this 'Wallpaper' folder is created  ?

Comment: Its in the Documents Directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the complete path of the directory.
I assume your folder `Wallpaper` is in the Documents Directory.

```
NSFileManager   *fileManager        =   [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString        *documentsPath      =   [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString        *extractDirPath     =   [documentsPath stringByAppendingString: @"/Wallpaper"];
NSArray         *extractsList       =   [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: extractDirPath error: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute path "/Wallpaper", but I guess your wallpaper folder is not in /?

```
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Wallpaper" error:NULL];
```

And try it like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Wallpaper" error:&error];
NSLog(@"load wallpaper error: %@", error);
```

This will give you the actual error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr= [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:Pathwithfoldername error:nil];
```